# How to add brightness UISlider on UIImagePickerController camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way by which I can add a `UISlider` to control the brightness on `UIImagePickerController` camera?

Comment: you can not add brightness on imagePickerController you can adjust it on image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do something like this is to not use UIImagePickerController and to create your own camera view. You take the feed from the camera and render it to the view directly. You can then edit the feed by changing the brightness etc...

There are a few really good videos from WWDC 2012 (I think session 510 and 511) that will explain how to do all of this well. It's actually fairly straight forward.

You can then add a button which acts as the camera button and saves the image.